# Find out what ElasticLinq is actually doing

Tags: c#, .net, linq, elasticsearch, elasticlinq

I've got an `ElasticDatastore` which I need to be able to return a list of documents based on arbitrary criteria in the business logic.

The method currently looks something like this...

```
private ElasticContext esLinq;

private void initialise() {
    esLinq = new ElasticContext(new ElasticConnection(endpoint, index: index));
}

public IEnumerable<Entities.Item> Items(Func<Entities.Item, bool> predicate) {
    var ret = esLinq.Query<Item>().Where(predicate);
    return ret;
}
```

I'm calling it like this

```
var newItems = dataStore.Items(x=>
        x.SomeField == node.SomeValue.ToString()
        & (x.AssignedTo == null
         | x.AssigmentExpires < DateTime.UtcNow)
    ).ToList();
```

As things stand, the method returns zero results. By using elastic head (and curl) I can verify that there are documents which match the specified criteria in the index.

My first guess is that the field names anticipated by EsLinq are incorrect (casing... the index was built using [nest](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/)). However, I can't find a good way to examine what EsLinq is actually sending to elasticsearch.

I can do

```
esLinq.Query<Item>().ToElasticSearchQuery();
```

And get a json string which represents the (blank) query, however, `...Query<Item>().Where(predicate)` returns an `IEnumerable<Item>` which doesn't have a `ToElasticSearchQuery` extension.

The compiler accepts

```
ret.AsQueryable().ToElasticSearchQuery()
```

but I get an `ArgumentException` at runtime:

```
Query must be of type IElasticQuery<> to call ToElasticSearchQuery()
```

How can I examine the query being sent by EsLinq to elasticsearch so I can diagnose the problem I'm hitting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install Fiddler you can see the exact HTTP being sent and returned. Alternatively you can use:

1. The .ToQueryInfo() method and examine the .Body and .Uri properties
2. The ILog interface on ElasticContext to capture the raw query and response

I would imagine the problem is that the mapping between your CLR objects and the document field name - by default the ElasticMapping class camel-cases field names and attempts to pluralize type names. You can turn this off with constructor switches or subclass it for your own specific conventions.

Additionally I think your query should say || for OR and && for AND - these boolean operators are supported but the | and & bitwise operations are not.